# Windows "forms" authentication - <deny users="?"> redirecting to foreign page!

Tags: asp.net, forms, authentication, web-config

Like the title states - I have a web.config file that looks like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
         <forms name="login" protection="All" timeout="30" loginUrl="login" defaultUrl="~/">
              <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
                   <user name="admin" password="password" /> 
              </credentials>
         </forms>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I want to do exactly what it says it should do... I want to deny all users who try to enter the site.

It works however, it redirects to a "Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2flogin" url I have never heard of...

Is there a place I can change this?

Comment: The problem here is that this URL: "Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2flogin" 
is generated from no where...

It seems to be a default thing...

I dont have an Account folder and I dont have routes that match Account/Login...

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this problem before. No doubt you're also getting this error:

> **Error message 401.2.:** Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

And you're being redirected to "/Account/Login" which doesn't even exist. I believe it's some kind of default that get's pulled in due to using MVC components **even if you're using an ASP.NET Forms website**. Perhaps you have some Razor pages and the following was added to your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Having this in there seems to be enough to mess up your login page as defined normally:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login" timeout="43200"/>
</authentication>
```

I've solved this by adding an extra "loginUrl" key to appSettings:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/Login.aspx" /><!-- Override default -->
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `loginUrl` param does not have an absolute path, so the path get mixed with the relative folder the website is.

Solution:

```
loginUrl="~/login"
```

or

```
loginUrl="/login"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
loginUrl="login"
```

This is the URL to send unauthenticated users to.  If the URL to your login page is "Login.aspx" then thats what you should set it too.

```
loginUrl="login.aspx"
```

The piece at the end, ReturnURL, is the address to redirect the user to if they successfully login.

Comment: It actually is not the problem. I use url routes and /login is a real location.

Even when changed to the local file name (login.aspx), I still get the same "uncontrolled" redirect.

Comment: This seems to me like it might be somehow related to your url routing, or at least it's worth investigating.  Can you post the config/code for your routing?

Comment: forget the routing... i'm confident it's not that...

the config is directing me to this page localhost:1234/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2flogin

the folder/page/variable/url/route "Account/Login" does not exist in my project at all.

How do I override this? Where is Account/Login being added into the mess?

Answer (score 0):

The LoginUrl is created with the code `UrlPath.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPathString, loginUrl);`, so I'm guessing somehow your root of your website is set to "Application".

http://www.ureader.com/msg/15372322.aspx